# Zipping files from a set using zipfile

Tags: python, windows, file

I need to zip specific files on a path all together.
I need to find certain files (for instance: AAA.txt, BBB.inf and etc) with exception to the ones that contain SFF in the name, and then zip them all together.

Every time I run this, I end up with my `DB.zip` with only `CCC.txt` inside. It means that every time the script finds a file from the set, it creates a new `DB.zip` with that new file inside, overwriting the previous one. How can I fix this?

```
import os
import zipfile

pr_directory = r'C:\Users\vijo9001\Desktop\Infact'
pr_path = os.listdir(pr_directory)
dst = r'C:\Users\vijo9001\Desktop\Infact'
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\vijo9001\Desktop\Infact')

my_set = {
"AAA",
"BBB",
"CCC"
}

for file in pr_path:
    zip_file = pr_directory + '/' + 'DB.zip'
    for x in my_set:
        if 'SFF' in file:
            continue
        if (str(x)) in file:
           zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "w",)
           zip.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
           zip.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question or problem with your code? Or are you looking for a code review?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I was expecting a review or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things about your code I spotted which you might want to  optimize/correct:

1. `zip` is instantiated within each iteration through the for loops, overriding each other.
   Meaning you will generate a DB.zip file for a file "AAA1.txt", then overwrite it with a DB.zip containing only a file "AAA2.txt", and so on. By initiating zip before the for loops you will add each file in turn, generating a single DB.zip containing all files.
2. Instead of having a for loop for every element in my_set, you can use a simple if-statement with the following condition:  `if any(x in file_split for x in my_set)`
3. `zip_file` would only need to be moved before the for loops to correctly declar `zip`
4. `zip` shadows the zip library, for better clarity and to avoid mistakes it would be better to rename the variable (I used zip_dir in the code below)

I played around with your code a bit and came up with the following snippet:

```
my_set = {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"}

zip_file = pr_directory + '/' + 'DB.zip'
zip_dir = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "w",)

for file in pr_path:
    if 'SFF' in file:
        continue
    if any(x in file for x in my_set):
        zip_dir.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

zip_dir.close()
```

This seems to work fine for me. Hope I was of help.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for taking the time and explaining it to me, that's really valuable since I'm on my second week of Python coding :)